# Extending .NET MembershipCreateStatus enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, membership-provider

Basically, what I'm trying to do is add more items to the basic MembershipCreateStatus enum packaged with .NET.  However, apparantly you can't do a "partial enum," like so:

```
public partial enum CreateMembershipStatus
{
    DuplicateCompany = 12,
    ActivityTooRecent = 13,
    MultipleMatches = 14
}
```

Is there a way for me add items to the CreateMembershipStatus list?  My goal is to deal with other predictable outcomes instead of just giving the user the catch all "User Rejected"

Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no way to do that - `partial` for classes is only possible to do within one project (the distinction between source files disappears upon compilation) anyway, and if it were possible for `enum`s, different additional values from different assemblies that happen to be mapped to the same underlying `int` values would clash, which is probably why such an extension is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot extend an enumeration because they are static and no adding the partial keyword won't work because it is not a class. You will need to create a custom container that contains all the membership statuses you want and then use that instead of the "CreateMembershipStatus" enum.

Answer (score 0):

To me seems like custom error handling that you can perform prior to making a call to `CreateUser()`. Or even better if you do it after `CreateUser()` call if it fails. In that case you can check the returned `MembershipCreateStatus` value and perform additional checks as per the status and return a custom message.

Comment: indeed, thats what i ended up doing, i was just hoping to extend the enumeration because i was being lazy :).